# Regular expression for a language which doesn't look regular

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to find a regular expression for the following language:

$$L=\{x0y : \text{$x$ contains same number of 0's as $y$ contains 1's}\}. $$

Comment: Usually I would ask what you have tried, but this is a trick question, which is hard to solve if you haven't seen the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to write $L$ as a different language. Let's consider the following similar language
$$ L' = \{ xy \in \{0,1\}^* : \#_0(x) = \#_1(y) \}, $$
where $\#_0(x)$ is the number of 0's in $x$.

I claim that $L' = (0+1)^*$. Indeed, let $w = w_1\ldots w_n$ be some arbitrary word, and define $\delta_w(i) = \#_0(w_1\ldots w_i) - \#_1(w_{i+1}\ldots w_n)$. The following properties are not hard to check:

1. $\delta_w(0) \leq 0$.
2. $\delta_w(n) \geq 0$.
3. $\delta_w(i+1) = \delta_w(i) + 1$ for $0 \leq i \leq n-1$.

This shows that $\delta_w(i) = 0$ for some $0 \leq i \leq n$, and so $w \in L'$.

Your case is very similar - I'll leave you to figure out the details.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what the x0y notation means?

Comment: It is the concatenation of three strings $x,0,y$. By the way, the first step toward solving a question is understanding it. You should have first asked for clarification regarding the question itself.

Comment: Two days ago we had that language! [Is language $\{a,b\}∗$
same as language $\{xy\in \{a,b\}^∗\mid |x|_a=|y|_b\}$
?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71221/4287)

Comment: @HendrikJan Indeed, the language had appeared even before that. It's a nice tricky exercise.