# Regular language with number of a's same as number of b's

Tags: regular-languages

L = { x^n y^n / x,y belongs to (a+b)^* , number of a's in x = number of b's in y and n > 0}

According to me it's regular because for any string $w$ belongs to $(a+b)^*$, we can divide the string into 2 parts $x$ and $y$ with $n=1$ .

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is quite incomplete. It doesn't constitute a proof. It doesn't explain *why* you can divide any string $w$ into two parts $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I just took many examples and noticed that for any string w, it can be divided into parts x and y. Like aaabbbaa into aaa (x) , bbbaaa(y).

Comment: That's fine, but how do you know that it's the case for *all* words? You need to prove it!

Comment: Still better, let someone else prove it: [Is language $\{a,b\}^∗$ same as language $\{xy\in \{a,b\}^∗\mid |x|_a=|y|_b\}$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71221)

Comment: @Hendrik Jan, Thanks for the link. So I think even this language is regular. We need to just put n=1.